# Swagger 415 Unsupported media type: application/json instead of text/plain in POST request

Tags: java, json, rest, content-type, swagger-ui

I have two REST-GUI's to test my REST-application.
One is created with swagger, and the other is Advanced REST Client which runs in Chrome.

I do a post to a service, the Swagger fails with error 415, and the Advanced Rest Client succeeds.

The difference between the two is the Content-Type in the request header. The OK-version has Content-Type: text/plain
The Error version has: Content-Type: application/json

For the rest, both are quite the same. I cut off the payload, but they are also exact the same in both cases.

I don't know how to change Content-Type in Swagger, if it is possible and if it is needed.

Below is information which you could need to help me in this issue. If you need more info, please need.

Thanks very much for any help.

Best regards.

The information look like:

---

**OK: Advanced REST Client**

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/oak-kernel-2.0/oak/archetype
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 OK

POST /oak-kernel-2.0/oak/archetype HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 10642
Origin: chrome-extension://hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 ....
Content-Type: text/plain
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1597438054.1422608427
```

Payload (fragment):

```
{"archetype": "archetype (adl_version\u003d1.4)\n\top........
```

Response:

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:87
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 30 Jan 2015 20:59:49 GMT
Server:Restlet-Framework/2.2.3
Vary:Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept
```

---

**ERROR: Swagger**

```
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/oak-kernel-2.0/oak/archetype
Request Method:POST
Status Code:415 Unsupported Media Type

POST /oak-kernel-2.0/oak/archetype HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 10642
Accept: application/json
Origin: http://localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 ....
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:8080/swagger/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,nl;q=0.6
Cookie: _ga=GA1.1.1597438054.1422608427
```

Payload (fragment):

```
{"archetype": "archetype (adl_version\u003d1.4)\n\top........
```

Response

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Content-Length:554
Content-Type:text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date:Fri, 30 Jan 2015 21:28:12 GMT
Server:Restlet-Framework/2.2.3
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If this helps anyone in the future,

In my case the error:

```
{
  "timestamp": "2019-01-22T18:23:48.989+0000",
  "status": 415,
  "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
  "message": "Content type '' not supported",
  "trace": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content type '' not supported

  [...]
}
```

I was putting in the @RequestMapping:

```
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

@RequestMapping(value = "/products", 
                consumes= APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, 
                produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class ProductResource {

 [...]

}
```

But I realized that what was generating this error was the 'consumes', removing it from @RequestMapping everything worked on the Swagger interface ui.

right:

```
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

@RequestMapping(value = "/products", 
                produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class ProductResource {

 [...]

}
```

Comment: When you use "@RequestMapping" instead of "@PostMapping" or "@GetMapping", you have to specify the HTTP request method ("method = RequestMethod.GET" or "method = RequestMethod.POST" for example). If you are using GET, it makes no sense to specify a content-type for the request body, and it will create an error.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer myself. I need to put a mediatype to the @Post-annotation in the Rest resource layer, like this

```
@Post("json")
```

Answer (score 0):

Was facing the same issue on Swagger Ui, removing "Consumes" from @RequestMapping worked for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
headers: <String, String>{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
```

Initially, it was like this:

```
    headers: <String, String>{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
```

and the later one returned this json from the GO swagger backend,

> {code: 415, message: unsupported media type "text/plain", only
> [application/json] are allowed}

Answer (score 0):

For me, my problem was the combined use of a `@RequestBody`, i.e. originally, my API endpoint looked like:

> public ResponseEntity<?> editDetails(@RequestBody @Valid
> EditDetailsRequestDto requestDto, @RequestPart @ApiParam(value="File")
> MultipartFile businessLicense) { ...

But when I changed `@RequestBody` to a bunch of `@RequestParam`s it fixed the 415 error.