# How to add 'appication/json' to a form part using swagger with openapi in spring

Tags: spring-boot, curl, swagger, openapi

I am having a controller with a jason part and a file part. The problem is when I try to execute it in swagger there is a `415 Unsupported Media Type`. Analyzing the curl there is that `application/json` part missing in the curl.

Here is the controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = "api/example", consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Void> example(@RequestPart @Valid @Parameter(content = @Content(mediaType = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, schema = @Schema(type = "object"))) ExampleDto exampleDto,
                                    @RequestPart(required = false) MultipartFile file) {
    // do something with the dto and the file
    return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
}
```

Here is the curl generated by swagger:

```
curl --location 'https://localhost:9090/api/example' \
--header 'accept: */*' \
--form 'exampleDto="{
  \"example\": \"string\"
}"' \
--form 'file=""'
```

And here is the working curl:

```
curl --location 'https://localhost:9090/api/example' \
--header 'accept: */*' \
--form 'exampleDto="{
  \"example\": \"string\"
}";type=application/json' \
--form 'file=""'
```

How can I achiev that with openapi in spring. I have tried with `@Content` part, but this does not do the trick :(

Comment: It's probably [this issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/4826) with Swagger UI.

Comment: Look into this it might help.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28245362/swagger-415-unsupported-media-type-application-json-instead-of-text-plain-in-po

Comment: I have a similar endpoint. I annotated MultipartFile with '@ModelAttribute' instead of '@RequestPart'. Works fine for me, you can try that.